# Compile Python script to standalone dll with Nuitka on Windows, to be used from c#

Tags: python, nuitka

I would like to compile a python script into a dll to be used form c#.
so far the script gets compiled into exe file and runs correctly.

how to make a dll?
the dll to be used from c#

I did not found a solution in Nuitka documentation.

Comment: Not the answer, but perhaps an idea, Why can't c sharp call an exe you create with nuitka? THey can communicate via sockets or pipes.

Comment: @gelonida : yes I try this route too. kind of rpc on pipes